# Modify string class to use only uppercase

Tags: ruby

I have a small application that processes some basic data (Names, birthdate, etc.).  It will be interfacing with a management system that only accepts uppercase strings.  Thinking of ways to go about this, I know I could just use .upcase for all the variables.  I figured the most DRY way would be to modify the String class itself and make a conversion, but could not find any documentation as to the method within String that actually takes in the value of said string.  The more I think about it, I also do not know what the implications of doing it this way would be (if it's even possible).

I tried monkey patching the String class

```
class String
  def initialize
    self = self.upcase
  end
end
```

Or

```
class String
  def new(str="")
    new_str = str.upcase
  end
end
```

But I haven't found any info on how a string is actually initialized.

**Tl;Dr**

1. How can I convert a lower case string to uppercase on said string's
   initialization
2. Are there any implications I should be aware of if it
       is possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Whatever your needs are, it is __never__ a good idea to amend a fundamental ruby class like this.

Comment: More curious on -is it doable- at this point.  I'm sure I will just utilize .upcase method.

Comment: Anything is "doable", just not advised. Better off creating your own method that does it automatically somehow

Comment: @NateBeers _sidenote:_ this particular “anything” is doable only via patching ruby’s [tag:c] code and recompiling your own version of it, due to strings might be initialized with _literals_: `str = "foo"`.

Comment: I figured that was the case, being so basic. @mudasobwa

Comment: _"It will be interfacing with a management system"_ – how? And where does the data (names, birthdate) come from?

Comment: @stefan taking user data from my script and filling forms within the management system.  Data is input by user with a gets, to keep it simple.

Comment: I understand the approach may not be advisable, Maybe I'm just thinking too far out of the box 

Comment: _"Data is input by user with a gets"_ – What about `def gets(*); super.upcase; end`? That would return any user input uppercased.

Comment: @Stefan Ahh I didn't think of that! That seems like the best way to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is not to boil the ocean and make every string in Ruby force everything to uppercase, but to uppercase the things that system needs **if and when** you provide it to that system.

Changing fundamental Ruby classes in this dramatic a way is bound to cause your entire code-base to implode. Many internals depend on being able to store arbitrary data in strings, and if those strings are arbitrarily uppercased you're in big trouble. It's like redefining what `Integer#+` does. You can, but you really, really shouldn't. This would be akin to redefining the electrical charge of a proton. The universe would literally explode.

It's better to write some kind of adapter method that can operate on arbitrary strings or values and make sure they conform to whatever quirks or encoding your other system uses:

```
def to_arcahic(string)
  string.upcase
end
```

If, for example, they don't allow accented characters or emoji, you'll need to strip those out and/or convert them to something else. Maybe "é" becomes "E" or maybe you just delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.